# How to get the filename of the download file from url using php/curl

Tags: filenames

I am having a url say : http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=1&Itemid=196

How to get the original Download filename using php like DOC_1998.pdf or so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for basename: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
$filename = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
```

Comment: If you're running PHP 5.2.0+ then I recommend: `$filename = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME); $filename = $filename['filename'];`